# managing the spaces between the pdf figures in latex document

Tags: spacing

I was creating a document containing pdf's figures  after finishing I have got the following style in my document(((attached picture))), I tried to manage the distance between these figures but when I changed them I got seperated figures while I want to keep them togather..I hope you can help me to sort this proplem out please.
Best Wishes[image: ADJUSTMENT OF SPACES BETWEEN PDF FIGURES]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[htb] 
\centering 
\begin{minipage}{.55\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{imagespar.pdf}
 \caption{optical micrograph images} 
\end{minipage}
 \hfill 
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{raman_partot.pdf}
\medskip
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{raman graph 1} 
\caption{raman graph 2}
 \end{minipage} 
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Code in comments doesn't really work, best to add it to the question in a code `{}` section, see my edit.

Comment: Replacing your images with example-image from the mwe package showed no problems.  The excessive gap on the right is in the image itself and will need to be cropped (or overlayed).  If you want to change the aspect ratio of the image on the left, simply specify the height separately from the width.